# Выяснилось, что скрипт вычисления разницы между датами работает неверно

Tags: php, дата

Недавно выяснил, что скрипт вычисления разницы между датами работает неверно.
Брал его, как говориться, из официальных источников.
[**рабочий пример здесь**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HEDukt)
Почему он выводит ошибочный расчёт?
Я просто влетел из-за этого по юбилею на другом проекте.
Что с ним не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!-- anniversary -->
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Krasnoyarsk');
$site_name_simple="test_name";
$a=mktime(0,0,0,02,09,2016);//вернет метку времени на 09/02/2016
$b=time();//текущая метка времени
$c=$a-$b;//время в секундах до 09 февраля 2016
$x=floor($c/60/60/24);
$x2=($c/60/60/24);
//echo "<span style='font: bold 1px \"Trebuchet MS\"; color:#FF0000'>".$x."</span>";//вывод

function numberEnd($number, $value, $suffix)
{
   //ключи массива suffix
   $keys = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);

   //берем 2 последние цифры
   $mod = $number % 100;

   //определяем ключ окончания
   $suffix_key = $mod > 4 && $mod < 21 ? 2 : $keys[min($mod%10, 5)];

   return $value . $suffix[$suffix_key];
}

if ($x > 1)
{
    $anniversary = "<div style='height:2px; width:0px;'></div>
        <span style='font: bold 24px \"Trebuchet MS\"; color:#2d9aff'>у ".$site_name_simple." скоро ЮБИЛЕЙ!<br>
        Через <span style='font: bold 36px \"Trebuchet MS\"; color:#ff0000'>".$x."</span> ".numberEnd($x, '', array('день', 'дня', 'дней'))."</span>
        <img src='images/10_years.png' style='position:relative; top:10px;' alt='картинка-поздравлялка'>
        <div style='height:30px; width:0px;'></div>";
}
    else
{
    if ($x < -99)
    {
        $anniversary = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $anniversary = "<div style='height:2px; width:0px;'></div>
        <span style='font: bold 28px \"Trebuchet MS\"; color:#2d9aff'>".$site_name_simple." отмечает ЮБИЛЕЙ!<br>
        <img src='images/10_years_complite.png' style='position:relative; top:10px;' alt='картинка-поздравлялка'>
        <div style='height:30px; width:0px;'></div>";
    }
}
print date("d.m.Y")."<br>";//текущая метка времени
print $anniversary;

?>
<!-- end anniversary -->
```

Comment: не используйте подсчет по секундам / микросекундам, используйте класс `DateTime` и его метод `diff()` для получения разницы между двумя датами.

Comment: @Etki, реализовал так:
Спасибо! Реализовал так: `$date_1 = new DateTime();
$date_2 = new DateTime('2016-02-09');
$interval = $date_2->diff($date_1);

// %a выведет общее количество дней.
echo $interval->format('%a total days');`
Но почему-то получается 108?

Comment: Потому что в интервале только 108 целых дней и еще какой-то остаток.

Comment: @Etki, Хотят закрыть вопрос почему-то. Пока не закрыли.
Почему-то с применением этих строк: `$interval = $b->diff($a);
// %a выведет общее количество дней.
$x= $interval->format('%a')+1;` у меня перестаёт работать сайт на зеркалах.
С чем такое странное поведение diff может быть связано?

Comment: С древней вверсией PHP, скорее всего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Etki прав, используйте [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php).

Могу предложить вам свою небольшую библиотеку по работе с датами [Rock Date](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-date).

Установка:

```
composer require romeoz/rock-date
```

Пример с diff:

```
// можно использовать и timestamp в качестве входных данных
$diff = (new DateTime('2015-02-01 00:00:00'))
          ->diff(new DateTime('2015-03-01 00:00:00'));

// Количество месяцев
echo $diff->m; // 1

// Количество дней
echo $diff->d; // 28
```

Comment: @I_CaR: Вы не тот плейсхолдер используете `echo $interval->format('%d дней');` Немного подправил [ваш пример](http://codepad.viper-7.com/O3Cwqr). `%R` - это знак разницы, ибо можно [полчить разницу](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fvkr6u) сколько дней осталось до какого-либо события.

Comment: @I_CaR: Да, всё врено `%a`. Единственное, что в нативной реализации нет возможности подсчитать общее количество месяцев, недель и т.д. Потому я предложил вам свою библиотеку, которая это решает, учитывая при этом разное количество дней в месяцах.

Comment: Спасибо! Да и мне и не нужно общее месяцев, недель. Реализовал так: `$date_1 = new DateTime();
$date_2 = new DateTime('2016-02-09');
$interval = $date_2->diff($date_1);

// %a выведет общее количество дней.
echo $interval->format('%a total days');`
Но почему-то получается 108?

Comment: @I_CaR: Вы получает разницу от текущей даты (`new DateTime()` это эквивалент `new DateTime('now')`) до `2016-02-09`. Она составляет `-108 дней`. Вот [результат](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xixPJD). Нужно помнить, что текущая дата `now` - это дата + время.

Comment: Хотят закрыть вопрос почему-то. Пока не закрыли.
Почему-то с применением этих строк: `$interval = $b->diff($a);
// %a выведет общее количество дней.
$x= $interval->format('%a')+1;` у меня перестаёт работать сайт на зеркалах. С чем такое странное поведение diff может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается вот где ошибка закралась!
Надо так:

```
$a=mktime(0,0,0,2,9,2016);
```

а не так:

```
$a=mktime(0,0,0,02,09,2016);
```