# Как найти все дни в промежутке между двумя датами?

Tags: php, дата

*PHP Date* - Как найти все дни в промежутке между двумя датами?

Например: *есть даты 25.10.2015 и 30.10.2015.*

*Как создать массив с датами, что находятся в промежутке?*

Нужен в итоге массив:

```
[0]=>26.10.2015  
[1]=>27.10.2015  
[2]=>28.10.2015  
[3]=>29.10.2015
```

Можно поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Плохо пользуетесь поиском. Так вопрос уже задавался и не раз. К примеру, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460479/10551

Comment: Покажите Ваш код с помощью которого вы пытались решить задачу. как именно Вы пытались получить желаемый результат? в чем у Вас возникла проблема?

Comment: @romeo он другое хочет сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

на английском уже отвечали [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451709/4953620)

```
function getDates($startTime, $endTime) {
    $day = 86400;
    $format = 'Y-m-d';
    $startTime = strtotime($startTime);
    $endTime = strtotime($endTime);
    //$numDays = round(($endTime - $startTime) / $day) + 1;
    $numDays = round(($endTime - $startTime) / $day); // без +1

    $days = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays; $i++) { 
        $days[] = date($format, ($startTime + ($i * $day)));
    }

    return $days;
}

$days = getDates('2012-05-12', '2012-05-16');
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2012-05-13
    [1] => 2012-05-14
    [2] => 2012-05-15
)
```

Тут первая и наследная даты включены.